# How can I get Firefox & IE to render writing-mode properly in a flexbox layout?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I'm using `writing-mode: vertical-lr` inside Flex box. The layout works properly in Chrome 76, but totally buggy in Firefox 68 & IE11.

**Note on requirement:** For a specific scenario, I need `%` vertical margins w.r.to container *(i.e., parent element)* height instead of width *(which is browser's actual behavior)*. Trick I'm using is, to set `writing-mode: vertical-lr` for container, so that the `%` vertical margins *(ex: `margin-top: 10%`)* of children will be calculated w.r.to container height instead of width. And I've applied `writing-mode: horizontal-tb` for children so that they appear normal.

**Demo code:** *(Run the below code in Firefox or IE 11, or see screenshots below)*

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container-vert  {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container-vert  > * {
  writing-mode: lr-tb;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  
  opacity: .8;
}


.c11 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.c12 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


.outer1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.outer2 {
  background-color: gold;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  writing-mode: lr-tb;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<p class="outer1">Before first example</p>
<div class="container-vert"> 
  <div class="c1 c11">Child1-1 element 
    <p>next line</p>
    <p>next line</p>
    <p>next line</p>
    <p>next line</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c1 c12">Child1-2 element
    <p>2nd's next line</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="outer1">After first example</p>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p class="outer2">Before second example</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">A</div>
  <div class="child">B</div>
  <div class="child">C</div>
  <div class="child">D</div>
  <div class="child">E</div>
</div>
<p class="outer2">After second example</p>
```

Is there any known fix to get Firefox & IE to render properly?

Chrome 76.0.3809.100:

[image: Chrome rendering properly]

---

Firefox 68.0.2:

[image: Firefox 68]

---

IE 11 & Edge 44.18362.267.0:

[image: IE 11 & Edge (pic1)]
[image: IE 11 & Edge (pic2)]
[image: IE 11 & Edge (pic3)]

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself instead of only linking to an off-site location that can and will change/die eventually.

Comment: @TylerH Added runnable code snippet.

Comment: For history purpose, Codepen link: https://codepen.io/manikantag/pen/jONrjBK

Answer (score 0):

You may have come to an over-complex way of doing what you want to do. If you want to have vertical margins based on the height, you can simply put an empty `div` with `height: X%;"` to emulate a margin. Remember that for percents to work well, all dimensioning in the hierarchy should be in percent too (Chrome may sometimes add extra rules for things to dimension "well" when it's not the normal behaviour, so I wouldn't myself base my styling on Chrome only).

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.margin {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html style="height:100%">
  <body style="height:100%">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: red;">BOO</div>
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: blue;">BOO</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another solution without needing extra divs. **NOTE: this may not be an easier solution** because here the margin height (the `::before`) is a percentage of the `.container` div (20% of 50% gives 10%), so that container `height` must include the margin in its own height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.margin::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html style="height:100%">
  <body style="height:100%">
    <div class="margin container" style="background-color: red;">BOO</div>
    <div class="margin container" style="background-color: blue;">BOO</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the spacer element solution already. But got issues with negative top margins while doing animations. Also, pseudo element doesn't push elements away when used in Flex & they can't be accessed in JS. After trying these 2 solutions only, I'm fiddling with `writing-mode`. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code (without using the writing-mode ,just using the Flexbox Layout):

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    .container-vert {
        background-color: lightcyan;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 125px;
        max-width: 125px;
    }
    .c11 {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }

    .c12 {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }


    .outer1 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .outer2 {
        background-color: gold;
    }


    .parent {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px dashed;
        background-color: lightblue;
        padding: 10px;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 125px;
        max-width:125px;
    }

    .row {
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .child {
        background-color: lightblue;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 10px;
        /*   margin: 10px; */
        min-width: 100px;
    }
</style> 

<p class="outer1">Before first example</p>
<div class="container-vert">
    <div class="c1 c11">
        Child1-1 element
        <p>next line</p>
        <p>next line</p>
        <p>next line</p>
        <p>next line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c1 c12">
        Child1-2 element
        <p>2nd's next line</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="outer1">After first example</p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p class="outer2">Before second example</p>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="child">A</div>
        <div class="child">B</div>
        <div class="child">C</div>
        <div class="child">D</div>
        <div class="child">E</div>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="outer2">After second example</p>
```

The result in the IE browser as below:

[image]

Comment: While the answer fixes the display on IE (and on Firefox too by the way), it disables the initial reason why the OP chose `flex` and `writing-mode`, which was to have % top and bottom margins based on the height of container instead of its width. With your solution, these margins are based on the width.

Comment: @Kaddath Exactly. Thanks for your comment. I thought to add the same.